# In a Powershell advanced function, how do I detect pipeline input in my BEGIN block?

Tags: function, powershell, pipeline

I have an advanced function

```
function Start-Executable {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param (
        [String]$Arg1,
        [String[]]$Arg2,
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true)][String[]]$PipeValue
    )

Begin {
    # Setup code
}
Process {
    # What goes on here?
    foreach ($val in $PipeValue) {
        # Process val here
    }
}
End {
}
}
```

In my setup code, I need to do something different depending on whether the user supplied pipeline input. But I don't know how I can tell in my BEGIN block if there's pipeline input. Is there something I can check for that?

One other thing I tried was putting the setup code in the PROCESS block, before the loop over `$PipeValue`, but that doesn't work because it appears that the PROCESS block is called once for each pipeline value, with `$PipeValue` being an array of one item each time. Is that right? If PROCESS is being called repeatedly for each value, why do I need *another* loop inside the PROCESS block?

**Update**

To clarify, what I'm trying to do is create a process in BEGIN, feed it input in PROCESS and read the output in END. For this to work I need to set `RedirectStandardInput` to `$true` if there is pipeline input, but not otherwise.

As workarounds, I can either make the user specify with an extra argument (and if they get it wrong, things don't work) or I can set a `$first_time` flag in BEGIN, then create the process the first time PROCESS is called. If I get to END without having created the process, I create it there with `RedirectStandardInput` as `$false`. That's more code duplication than I like, but if it's the only option I may have to do it that way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Begin block runs before the pipeline is started, so there's no way for that code to know what's in the pipeline.

As far as needing another loop inside the Process block, you have to have that if the function needs to accept whatever $PipeValue is as either pipeline input or passed as a parameter.  If it's only going to accept that as pipeline data, then there's no point in having a parameter for it.  Just use $_ inside the process block.

Comment: Exactly - well designed cmdlets support input via the pipeline or directly as a parameter.  It's a little annoying to need the loop in your process block, but it's a better experience for users of the cmdlet.

Comment: Usually, yes.  To pass data as a parameter, that data must be resident in memory.  In some cases a function may be intended for use with a dataset that should only be handled via the pipeline to avoid memory exhaustion.

Comment: OK, thanks. So essentially there's no way to have setup code that depends on whether there's pipeline data. That's a nuisance (I'll edit my post to explain why, too much to add here) but I have a clumsy workaround I can use if I have to.

Comment: @Jason Shirk -- The `process{}` block is to accomodate pipeline input.  The `foreach()` loop inside the `process{}` block is to accomodate array arguments.  The `begin`, `process` and `end` keywords are ignored when no pipeline input is received, in which case the script will run 1x through, start to finish.

Answer (score 22):

`$MyInvocation.ExpectingInput` returns true if the function is invoked with pipeline input, and false otherwise.

This works in `begin`, `process`, and `end` blocks. It does not work in `dynamicparam` [in PowerShell 5.1 or lower](https://windowsserver.uservoice.com/forums/301869-powershell/suggestions/13737072--myinvocation-expectinginput-doesn-t-work-%5Din-dynam).

Comment: This right here should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
function Start-Executable {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param (
        [String]$Arg1,
        [String[]]$Arg2,
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true, parametersetname="nopipeline")][String[]]$PipeValue
    )

Begin {
    # Setup code
    if($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName -eq "nopipeline")
    {
        Write-Host "No pipeline input"
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Host "Pipeline input"
    }
}
Process {
    $PipeValue
}
End {
}
}
```

This seems to do the trick.
Basically, the parameter is assigned to a parameter set.
If the parameter is used, `$pscmdlet.ParameterSetName` contains `"nopipeline"`.
If using the pipeline, then `$pscmdlet.ParameterSetName` contains `"__AllParameterSets"`

Sample output:

```
PS H:\> @("a","b","c") | Start-Executable
Pipeline input
a
b
c

PS H:\> Start-Executable -PipeValue @("a","b","c")
No pipeline input
a
b
c
```

Edit: Note that this however won't tell you that there *is* pipeline input. It will tell you whether the named parameter was used.
In other words, this happens:

```
PS H:\> Start-Executable
Pipeline input
```

Comment: But this won't work if I just do `Start-Executable` without either pipeline input or an argument, presumably? I guess I could put together an even more complicated set of parameters declarations that might work, but it seems like a lot of effort... (BTW, I don't actually *want* `Start-Executable -PipeValue @("a","b","c")` to work, although I'm willing to put up with it if I can't avoid it.

Comment: I actually amended my answer about this, you're right :) If you don't need "-Pipevalue" to work, why not go with mjolinor's answer, and remove the parameter altogether?